# Cannot get input stream working in SBCL sb-ext:run-program

Tags: common-lisp, inputstream, sbcl, external-process

While the following works:

```
(let* ((i (make-string-input-stream "foo bar baz"))
       (p (sb-ext:run-program "/bin/cat" '() 
              :input i :output *trace-output* :wait t)))
  (sb-ext:process-close p))
```

the code below does not - it will stop after writing "001":

```
(let* ((_1 (format t "001~%"))
       (p (sb-ext:run-program "/bin/cat" '() 
              :input :stream :output *trace-output* :wait t))
       (_2 (format t "010~s~%" p))
       (s (sb-ext:process-input p)))
  (declare (ignore _1 _2))
  (format s "foo bar baz~%")
  (finish-output s)
  (sb-ext:process-close p))
```

So it seems to silently leave execution in `sb-ext:run-program`.

This is with SBCL 1.3.6 on Ubuntu 16.04.1.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance, Frank

Comment: `:WAIT T` means wait until the process exits.

Comment: The `:wait t` is there in both cases, also in the working case - so this cannot be the explanation. Also the issue is not that `sb:ext-run-program` is leaving its own execution, the whole `let` blog is left without running displaying any log output - and this would not be expected even with `:wait nil`. Thanks anyway,

Comment: In the first case you're giving it a string input stream. `cat` reads the input until it EOFs and then returns. In the second example you're not writing anything to the stream, so there will not be EOF and `cat` will keep waiting forever for more input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, the problem is the `:WAIT T` argument. It causes the call to `SB-EXT:RUN-PROGRAM` to not return until the child process exits.

In the first example you passed a string input stream to the child process. `cat` will read input from the stream, and when the input ends there will be a End of File, so `cat` exits. In the second example there is no input available for the program, so it's effectively an infinite loop (just like if you run `cat` on the command line, and don't give any input to it; it will never exit).

The solution is to use `:WAIT NIL`. You will also have to close the input stream with `CLOSE`, because otherwise there will be no EOF and `cat` keeps listening for more input. You'll also want to use `SB-EXT:PROCESS-WAIT` after closing the stream to wait for `cat` to exit itself.

```
(let* ((p (sb-ext:run-program "/bin/cat" '() 
                              :input :stream
                              :output *standard-output*
                              :wait nil))
       (s (sb-ext:process-input p)))
  (format s "foo bar baz~%")
  (finish-output s)
  (close s)
  (sb-ext:process-wait p)
  (sb-ext:process-close p))
```

I'm not sure why you used `*TRACE-OUTPUT*` for the child output, so I changed it to `*STANDARD-OUTPUT*`.

Also, using `FORMAT` for debugging like that is kind of ugly. Common Lisp provides actual debugging tools. In this case you could use [`STEP`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_step.htm):

```
(step (let* ((p (sb-ext:run-program "/bin/cat" '() 
                                    :input :stream
                                    :output *standard-output*
                                    :wait nil))
             (s (sb-ext:process-input p)))
        (format s "foo bar baz~%")
        (finish-output s)
        (close s)
        (sb-ext:process-wait p)
        (sb-ext:process-close p)))
```

This will put you in the debugger, showing the call being evaluated next. You can invoke the `STEP-NEXT`-restart to continue to the next call.

Comment: OK - thanks again. I get your points - and will concentrate on the main issue now. What I don't understand here: also for the second example I do provide input for the process and I finish/flush that input stream - both actions done through stream `s`. I also got confused, since Emacs/Slime don't block the waiting process, the REPL is still responsive. When testing in the SBCL REPL, the waiting process really blocks. Anyway I tried the `wait nil`as you proposed and ... it worked ;) So I still don't get it completely, but I have a solution - thanks again.

Comment: @FrankRuben Emacs/Slime makes use of different threads. The REPL uses its own thread, whereas others tasks are executed using "worker" threads. Use slime-list-threads to list them. When you run SBCL on your own, you are only interacting with a single thread. You could use sb-thread:make-thread to start another one and the result would be similar to what you observe within Emacs.

Answer (score 0):

This is what works, as suggested by [jkiiski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5747548/jkiiski):

```
(let* ((p (sb-ext:run-program "/bin/cat" '() 
                              :input :stream 
                              :output *standard-output* 
                              :wait nil))
       (s (sb-ext:process-input p)))
  (format s "foo bar baz~%")
  (finish-output s)
  (sb-ext:process-wait p)
  (sb-ext:process-close p))
```